# Detect data-rel="back" in ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am wondering if it is possible for an ASP.NET MVC Controller to detect when a user has gone back a page via data-rel="back".

My markup contains

```
    <a some-attributes="SomeValue" data-rel="back" >Back</a>
```

And the method on my controller is something along the lines of

```
    public ActionResult SomeMethodName(SomeModel model)
    {
          bool ArrivedViaDataRelBack = //somehow detect user hit back/got here via data-rel="back"
          if (ArrivedViaDataRelBack) 
          {
              //Do Something 
          }
          else 
          {
             //Do Something else. 
          }

    }
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible since that data isn't sent to the server.
If you want to do that you should include it in the URL:

```
<a some-attributes="SomeValue" data-rel="back" href="/YourController/SomeMethodName?ArrivedViaDataRelBack=true" >Back</a>
```

Note: this is obviously lacking your model, so you'd have to add that.

Then you can change your method like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeMethodName(bool ArrivedViaDataRelBack, SomeModel model)
{
     if (ArrivedViaDataRelBack) 
      {
          //Do Something 
      }
      else 
      {
         //Do Something else. 
      }
}
```